# What is "soon's"?

Tags: phrases, contractions

From novel *To Kill A Mockingbird*:

> I'd soon's kill you as look at you.

What is "soon's" short for? I had found a similar sentence

> would as soon do something as look at you

So as soon as can be shortened to soon's as?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22soon%20as%20look%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Answer (score 7):

"soon's" is short for "soon as".

"I would as soon as do X as do Y" is an idiom of sorts meaning "I would be just as likely to do X as to do Y". This is usually used to make some humorous comparison between a routine action and some extreme action, like here: "I'd as soon as kill you as look at you", meaning, next time I meet you, I would be just as likely to kill you as to simply look at you. A less dramatic example would be, "I'd as soon as quit as have to work a day like that one again".

It is also said without the second "as": "I would as soon do X as do Y". Like here that would be, "I would as soon kill you as look at you."

Note that "as soon as" also has a more literal meaning: at the instant the event happens. Like, "As soon as Harold arrives, we will begin the meeting." Or, "I'll call you as soon as I arrive in Pittsburgh."

Comment: You might want to answer the last sentence directly as well, where they seem to be asking whether “soon’s” is a standard contraction they should start using in their own writing.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Fair enough: The answer is "no", this is not a standard contraction. It's recognizable but would be considered very informal, perhaps slang or dialect.

Answer (score 6):

It's a cut-down representation of...

> *I would **as** soon [as] kill you **as** look at you*
>    (i.e. - *I would kill you **as** soon/easily/casually **as** [I would] look at you*<sup>1</sup>)

...where although the second *[as]* is grammatically incorrect, it's not uncommon in uneducated and/or dialectal speech. Note that although in "standard" speech it's quite normal to reduce the vowel sound in ***as*** to a neutral schwa, it's *not* normal to delete it completely (so *I'd as soon die's diet* is never valid).

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the standard "matched pair" construction (OP's "ungrammatical" cited usage has *three* ***as***'s).

Comment: You mean "I would as soon as kill you as look at you" is grammatically incorrect (though valid in speech) and would be more formal to say "I would as soon kill you as look at you"?

Comment: And "I'd soon's kill you as look at you." is in general a invalid speech since it misses a in as completely? (It makes sense as it was said by an uneducated child.)

Comment: No - it's invalid because (putting aside the elision of the vowel) there are ***three*** instances of the word ***as***, when they should always appear as a matched ***pair*** in this construction. Whether "dialectal" is the same as "uneducated" is a moot point, but from your perspective as a learner, you would be well advised not to copy the usage yourself.

Comment: You might want to answer the last sentence directly as well, where they seem to be asking whether “soon’s” is a standard contraction they should start using in their own writing.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I think that would open things up a bit *too* much! I did edit to reflect the fact that we don't normally dispense with the vowel completely in either instance of **as** in this matched pair usage. But the reality is that although it's an extremely unusual *eye dialect* representation, lots of perfectly articulate educated speakers are quite capable of responding to *When can we start?* with *Soon's you like!* For the most part I think learners should avoid using contractions *unless* they're repeating forms they often hear/see many other people use. They're easy to get wrong.